# Machine learning which algorithm to choose

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I am trying to build a article recommendation system to users based on theire intention. Each user will select an intention. Example are :

1- To live an healthy life

2- Be relaxed and refreshed

3- Get a job

4- Know about technology

etc. I have say 20 such intentions defined. I have web contents scrapped from few blogs & web sites and its links.I nees to suggest the relevent links to users based on intention selected. 
Question :

I suppose this can be best solved with unsupervised machine learning algorithm. Is this the correct approach ?

Possible steps to solve this ( nees to consider scalability ) or algorthms or best tools 
(I prefer python)? I found genisim library is this apt for this ?

Comment: No.





Ok, just kidding... well, at stackoverflow you are expected to show what you have tried already, and you are just asking a very broad question.

Comment: @JosepValls : I have 2 questions explained at the bottom for my problem. I don't think these are very broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the comments an answers to this point are correct: there is no way to specify the "best" model at the outset. I am adding this answer to point to a non-technical discussion of the reasons behind this: [No Free Lunch Theorem for Machine Learning](http://www.statsblogs.com/2014/01/25/machine-learning-lesson-of-the-day-the-no-free-lunch-theorem/), as well as a mathematical discussion [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6783/2015fa/lec3.pdf).

Hopefully these links are useful for people who come across this question later.

Answer (score 2):

As @Root has said and many others have already proved **Their is no single best algorithm that works for all cases**.

You have to build models and evaluate/tune/refine them and measure their accuracy. Use single algorithm which has the highest accuracy (You can also consider performance, scalability, easy implementation parameters) or mixture of algorithms (model ensemble) as the preferred model.

Coming to your problem, I think neural network is one of the algorithms for such recommendation and easy to start with. Later on you can also look for classification trees, Deep learning etc.

I hope this helps to start.

Answer (score 1):

in general, no one can recommend the "best" algo except in very particular use cases.

think deeply about the relationships between your variables and what your data looks like. the right algorithm will either be clear as a bell or require experimentation. no one can tell you what to use.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand what you are looking for, therefore understand the question / goal. What are you trying to figure out. Then either write it down very specifically and then turn it into statistical question. For  ex. I want a probability that it might rain tomorrow. 
1) If you are trying to predict a target value, then go for supervised learning.
2) If not, then unsupervised learning.
3) What values do you have? Discrete, Categorical?
4) If you are looking for yes / no type answer then go for classification.
5) If the target value could be any number, then go for regression.
6) If you are not trying to predict a target value, then you go for unsupervised learning.
7) Are you trying to fit some values into discrete groups, then go for clustering.
8) If you want to know how strong a fit is then use density estimation algorithm.

Read The elements of statistical learning and machine learning with Python / R for more. Happy Learning!